# "Twitching" When Using JQuery hover to clip my Bootstrap card

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue where when I click on a `font awesome` icon my `card` flips (got this working fine) but when I `hover` over the `icon` it "twitches" and sometimes starts flipping the card but then stops.

I have created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/murday1983/0gr5endp/6/) with all my code i'm using and its also doing it in this also, so I know its nothing that's overwriting anything in my code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="col" class="col-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="flip">
        <div id="trunkCard" class="card">
            <div class="face front">
                <div class="card-body" style="padding-top: .5rem">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-12 pr-0" style="display: inline-flex">
                            <div class="alert-success card-icon w-100">
                                <canvas id="extensions" class=""></canvas>
                            </div>
                            <i id="trunkIcon" class="fas fa-info-circle fa-4x text-info pl-3" style="cursor: pointer; height: fit-content"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row dashboardCardHeadingRow">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="card-subtitle text-muted">Extensions</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row text-center">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="card-subtitle text-muted">Billable</div>
                            <h4 class="mb-0">0</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="card-subtitle text-muted">Non-billable</div>
                            <h4 class="mb-0">0</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="face back">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat animi nobis quia. Adipisci veritatis nihil, quo impedit aliquid provident maxime
                        maiores
                        explicabo incidunt. Iste ea eius rem eveniet! Atque, exercitationem?</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat animi nobis quia. Adipisci veritatis nihil, quo impedit aliquid provident maxime
                        maiores
                        explicabo
                        incidunt. Iste ea eius rem eveniet! Atque, exercitationem?</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat animi nobis quia. Adipisci veritatis nihil, quo impedit aliquid provident maxime
                        maiores
                        explicabo
                        incidunt. Iste ea eius rem eveniet! Atque, exercitationem?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#extInfoIcon").hover(function () {
    $('#extCard').addClass('flipped');
 }, function () {
     $('#extCard').removeClass('flipped');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.flip {
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
    perspective: 800;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.flip .card.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    transform: rotatey(-180deg);
}

.flip .card {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.flip .card .face {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
}

.flip .card .front {
    z-index: 1;
}

.flip .card .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    position: absolute;
}
```

Again, this is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/murday1983/0gr5endp/6/) using the above code.

Comment: So you finally want it to stop right there on the flipped side, right ? But then how will it return ? or am I missing something ?

Comment: @Rex5 The issue is when they move the mouse to the icon, it glitches most of the time.  The only way i can this is to display another icon which stops this but i'd rather not introduce additional code if it can be helped and somehow fix the gliching

Comment: Interesting question regarding events and behaviors surrounding them.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not what you're asking, but why don't you toggle the class on click? 
IMO the hover event doesn't work well on this case becase as soon as the cursor is on the icon the class is added and the animation starts. If you by accident move the cursor a little bit the animation re-starts resulting on the twitch you see.

Personally I'd change the add/remove class bit to:

`$("#extInfoIcon").click(function () {
    $('#extCard').toggleClass('flipped');
}`

Then just add another click event handler to turn it back again.
Twitch gone.

Comment: I do agree here the `hoover` event is probably not the optimal approach but, as you say this is not the desired behavior asked for either - although neither the `hover` or `click` seems super intuitive it's not really our choice of behavior either but that of the OP..

Answer (score 0):

This is easily smoothed out by using `.one(` in a creative manner, adding it when the `mouseenter` event happens, trigger a custom `'setflip'` event then when you leave the back card or if it is clicked, it is flipped back.

```
$("#extInfoIcon").on('mouseenter', function() {
  $('#extCard').addClass('flipped');
  $(".face.back").trigger('setflip');
});
$(".face.back").on('setflip', function(event) {
  $(this).one('mouseleave, click', function() {
    $('#extCard').removeClass('flipped');
  });
});
```

Comment: This is not truly "100%" of the actual behavior but should perform the same as a net result.  Remove the `"click"` event option if that does not add value to you. Rather than "fix" the "glitching" this should avoid it entirely.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that when the card flips, the mouse "exits" the icon and the `mouseleave` handler is executed, removing the `flipped` class, then it starts to come back to its original place, the mouse "enters" the icon and the class is removed, causing the twitching.

One solution would be to attach the handler to some other event. Another workaround, that you might find more convenient, is to wait for the card to completely flip, before checking if we *still have the user's attention*, for example, we can flip the card when the user hovers over the icon, then wait 1 second and after that, check if the pointer is still over the card, if it isn't, then flip it back.

The timer also works well as a delay between the pointer leaving the card and it's flipping back, but if you don't like that effect, you can remove it later.

```
const $card = $('#extCard');
let focus = false,
  t;

$("#extInfoIcon").mouseenter(function () {
  $card.addClass('flipped');
});

$card.hover(() => {
  focus = true;
  clearTimeout(t);
}, function () {
  focus = false;
  t = setTimeout(() => {

    // Check if we still have 'focus' i.e. the pointer is in the card
    if (!focus) {
      $card.removeClass('flipped');
    }

  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I don't think adding a global/larger scoped `$card` `'focus`, and `t` is good practice